# How can I ignore spaces in mysql search query with LIKE?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a program where a user searches for a "course" by course code or name. I am trying to make it so if the user searches "CODE1002", CODE 1002 EL from the database will still return (there is a space). As indicated by other posts I have tried to use the REPLACE function with no success.

**Here is my current code (however it does not ignore spaces):**

```
$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses WHERE (course_code LIKE :searchText OR course_name LIKE :searchText)) AS course_count, course_id, course_code, course_name FROM courses WHERE (course_code LIKE :searchText OR course_name LIKE :searchText) ORDER BY course_code LIMIT 6');

$final_search_term = "%".$search_term."%";
$records->bindParam(':searchText', $final_search_term);
```

**Here is my attempt at adding REPLACE to ignore spaces on the course_code with no success:**

```
$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM courses WHERE (REPLACE(course_code,' ','') LIKE :searchText OR course_name LIKE :searchText)) AS course_count, course_id, course_code, course_name FROM courses WHERE (REPLACE(course_code,' ','') LIKE :searchText OR course_name LIKE :searchText) ORDER BY course_code LIMIT 6');

$final_search_term = "%".$search_term."%";
$records->bindParam(':searchText', $final_search_term);
```

The first code works perfectly aside from not ignoring spaces.

Comment: may be esier to do the replacing in php first

Comment: Shouldn't REPLACE be on the right side of LIKE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are putting the replace on the wrong side.  Just to be safe, let's do it for both operands:

```
REPLACE(course_code, ' ', '') LIKE REPLACE(:searchText, ' ', '')
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why the following is not working? SELECT course_id, course_code, course_name FROM courses WHERE (REPLACE(courses.course_code, ' ', '') LIKE REPLACE(\'%COSC 2%\', ' ', '')) ORDER BY course_code LIMIT 6   I am trying to test a smaller portion and I have concluded that \'%COSC 2%\' is causing the issue. Nothing returns however when I do this in phpmyadmin it returns the correct results (after removing the escapes (\)) :S

Comment: @JasonFel . . . You don't want the backslashes in the SQL code.  You just want the single quote.