# WordPress: How to make search query ignore spaces in results?

Tags: sql, wordpress

Say I have a product with code ABCD EFG

If I search ABCD EFG it will work.

Is there a way to have the product show up if I search for ABCDEFG? In other words, ignoring the space in the title?

Basically I want [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090795/how-can-i-ignore-spaces-in-mysql-search-query-with-like). Is there a way to modify the search query using a filter through WordPress to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you need to return the same results if the space is there or not? If you need a more advanced search, I would highly recommend installing Relevannsi.

Comment: Yes the product should show up if either "ABCD EFG" or "ABCDEFG" is searched for.